# Heroku - Setting 1 dyno costs money

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Whenever I set 1 dyno up using this command

```
heroku ps:scale web=1
```

Then I go to check my resources, I see that it costs me 7 dollars, I don't know why since it's a personal app not a an application in a heroku team

It's a ROR application, I'm using both PostgreSQL and MongoDB add-ons which are free

I need to use the 1 free dyno but I looked through the free plan and Dyno configuration on Heroku and I can't get anywhere, any help ?

Comment: You've made a series of statements here, but I don't see a question. If there is a question, does it seem more appropriate for Heroku support or Stack Overflow?

Comment: I edited the question, I'll try Heroku support as well

Comment: Why and where are you using 'heroku ps:scale web=1', i uploaded many apps on Heroku and i never used that before?

Comment: Because whenever I check my dynos and workers using `heroku ps` I find no dynos on my application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, there are 3 types of dynos

1-free

2-hobby

3-standard

Since my application was in team mode then changed to perosnal app, the dyno type didn't change and it was still hobby, I had to change the dyno type using this command

Example

```
heroku dyno:type web=free
```

After changing dyno type, you can make it up with this command with no cost on your credit card

```
heroku ps:scale web=1
```

Comment: After issuing `heroku dyno:type web=free` for an app within a team, I got the message: *Heroku Teams only support hobby and professional dynos.*